# Where do I find "Broadcast to LAN" in Minecraft on iPad?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ios

We are trying to set up to play Minecraft together with two iPads.  I have read several instructions, including some here, but I am stopped at the step of turning on "Broadcast to LAN" that is referred to in most instructions.  I believe I have the Bedrock version of the game loaded and v1.19.10.  I am connected to my local wifi network,  I've toured all the "Settings" menus I can find, but cannot find the "Broadcast to LAN" setting to select.  Can someone help me get set up?

Also, I did find "Multiplayer Game" & "Visible to LAN Players" selections in the "Multiplayer" main button options in "Setting" after pausing the game, but those selections were greyed out and I could not turn them on.  ?

Comment: The reason you initially had a problem is that you were following a guide for Minecraft: Java Edition. Java runs on PC and Mac, while Bedrock Edition is Windows 10/11, console, mobile, and VR. In the future, look for "Bedrock" or include it in your search to make sure whatever information you're looking for is applicable to your version. If you'd like to learn more about the differences between them, view [this blog post](https://minecraft.net/article/java-or-bedrock-edition) or [documentation article](https://docs.microsoft.com/minecraft/creator/documents/differencesbetweenbedrockandjava).

Answer (score 1):

As long as both iPads are connected the same network, the game should appear in the "Friends" menu for the second device. The trick is that most settings cannot be adjusted while in the world, you need to first exit by pressing <kbd>Save and Quit</kbd> in the pause menu, and then open the world settings by pressing the 'pencil' icon next to the world. On the left, open the <kbd>Multiplayer</kbd> tab where you can configure a few options, including enabling LAN multiplayer. Once enabled, press <kbd>Play</kbd> at the top to enter the world again, and you should be able to join on the second device.

For more information, check out [this support article](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/4410316619533-How-to-Play-Minecraft-Multiplayer#h_01FGSN7J5XN4AAVSCVSBNGVS90).